# Iterate over Dataframe & Recursive filters

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have 2 dataframes. "MinNRule" & "SampleData"
MinNRule provides some rule information based on which SampleData needs to be:

1. Aggregate "Sample Data" on columns defined in MinNRule.MinimumNPopulation and MinNRule.OrderOfOperation
2. Check if Aggregate.Entity >= MinNRule.MinimumNValue

   a. For all Entities that do not meet the MinNRule.MinimumNValue, remove from population

   b. For all Entities that meet the MinNRule.MinimumNValue, keep in population
3. Perform 1 through 2 for next MinNRule.OrderOfOperation using 2.b dataset

```
MinNRule
| MinimumNGroupName | MinimumNPopulation | MinimumNValue | OrderOfOperation |
|:-----------------:|:------------------:|:-------------:|:----------------:|
|       Group1      | People by Facility |       6       |         1        |
|       Group1      |  People by Project |       4       |         2        |

SampleData

| Facility  | Project   | PeopleID  |
|:--------: |:-------:  |:--------: |
|    F1     |    P1     |  166152   |
|    F1     |    P1     |  425906   |
|    F1     |    P1     |  332127   |
|    F1     |    P1     |  241630   |
|    F1     |    P2     |  373865   |
|    F1     |    P2     |  120672   |
|    F1     |    P2     |  369407   |
|    F2     |    P4     |  121705   |
|    F2     |    P4     |  211807   |
|    F2     |    P4     |  408041   |
|    F2     |    P4     |  415579   |
```

Proposed Steps:

1. Read MinNRule, read rule with OrderOfOperation=1

   a. GroupBy Facility, Count on People

   b. Aggregate SampleData by 1.a and compare to MinimumNValue=6

```
        | Facility  | Count     | MinNPass  |
        |:--------: |:-------:  |:--------: |
        |    F1     |    7      |  Y        |
        |    F2     |    4      |  N        |
```

2. Select MinNPass='Y' rows and filter the initial dataframe down to those entities (F2 gets dropped)

```
            | Facility  | Project   | PeopleID  |
            |:--------: |:-------:  |:--------: |
            |    F1     |    P1     |  166152   |
            |    F1     |    P1     |  425906   |
            |    F1     |    P1     |  332127   |
            |    F1     |    P1     |  241630   |
            |    F1     |    P2     |  373865   |
            |    F1     |    P2     |  120672   |
            |    F1     |    P2     |  369407   |
```

3. Read MinNRule, read rule with OrderOfOperation=2

   a. GroupBy Project, Count on People

   b. Aggregate SampleData by 3.a and compare to MinimumNValue=4

```
        | Project   | Count     | MinNPass  |
        |:--------: |:-------:  |:--------: |
        |    P1     |    4      |  Y        |
        |    P2     |    3      |  N        |
```

4. Select MinNPass='Y' rows and filter dataframe in 3 down to those entities (P2 gets dropped)
5. Print Final Result

```
            | Facility  | Project   | PeopleID  |
            |:--------: |:-------:  |:--------: |
            |    F1     |    P1     |  166152   |
            |    F1     |    P1     |  425906   |
            |    F1     |    P1     |  332127   |
            |    F1     |    P1     |  241630   |
```

Ideas:

1. I have been thinking of moving MinNRule to a LocalIterator and loopinng through it and "filtering" SampleData
2. I am not sure how to pass the result at the end of one loop over to another
3. Still learning Pyspark, unsure if this is the correct approach.
   I am using Azure Databricks

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, since the rules df defines the rules therefore it must be small and can be collected to the driver for performing the operations on the main data.

One approach to get the desired result can be by collecting the rules df and passing it to the reduce function as:

```
data = MinNRule.orderBy('OrderOfOperation').collect()

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from functools import reduce

dfnew = reduce(lambda df, rules: df.groupBy(col(rules.MinimumNPopulation.split('by')[1].strip())).\
       agg(count(col({'People':'PeopleID'}.get(rules.MinimumNPopulation.split('by')[0].strip()))).alias('count')).\
       filter(col('count')>=rules.MinimumNValue).drop('count').join(df,rules.MinimumNPopulation.split('by')[1].strip(),'inner'), data, sampleData)

dfnew.show()

+-------+--------+--------+
|Project|Facility|PeopleID|
+-------+--------+--------+
|     P1|      F1|  166152|
|     P1|      F1|  425906|
|     P1|      F1|  332127|
|     P1|      F1|  241630|
+-------+--------+--------+
```

Alternatively you can also loop through the df and get the result the performance remains same in both the cases

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
mapped_cols = {'People':'PeopleID'}
data = MinNRule.orderBy('OrderOfOperation').collect()
for i in data:
    cnt, grp = i.MinimumNPopulation.split('by')
    cnt = mapped_cols.get(cnt.strip())
    grp = grp.strip()
    sampleData = sampleData.groupBy(f.col(grp)).agg(f.count(f.col(cnt)).alias('count')).\
    filter(f.col('count')>=i.MinimumNValue).drop('count').join(sampleData,grp,'inner')

sampleData.show()
+-------+--------+--------+
|Project|Facility|PeopleID|
+-------+--------+--------+
|     P1|      F1|  166152|
|     P1|      F1|  425906|
|     P1|      F1|  332127|
|     P1|      F1|  241630|
+-------+--------+--------+
```

**Note: You have to manually parse your rules grammar as it is subjected to change**

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out. Regarding rules grammar, I plan on using a dict to allow me to look up what needs to be "Grouped" and what needs to be "counted" and then pass those into reduce

Comment: Alternatively you can also pass a third argument to reduce with partial containing your rules dict

Comment: Accept the answer if it helps :)